# Why is it not possible to include or embed a file in HTML

Tags: html, include, embed

I use PHP to include common areas like navigation menu and footer in all my files. But why doesn't HTML have such a provision. After all, it allows us to reference CSS and other files. Is it that difficult to come up with a solution to embed an external file in an HTML file?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with just HTML but you can use Server Side Includes.

```
<mytag>
    <!--#include file="included.html" -->
</mytag>
```

Take a look to these docs:

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/webmaster/article.php/3473341/SSI-The-Include-Command.htm

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/ssi.html

Answer (score 0):

as rafa mentioned,
you could also use php functions like:
`require_once($path)` or `include($path)`
where $path is the path of your external file that you what to include.
For example: you have the file footer.php that has everything you want actually:

```
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<ul>
  <li>Menu Item 1</li>
  <li>Menu Item 3</li>
  <li>Menu Item 3</li>
  <li>.....</li>
</ul>
<p>This is another paragraph</p>
```

Now, in your index.php file or any file you have, you could write something like:

```
<?php $path_footer = "footer.php"; require_once($path_footer); ?>
```

and this line of code will display the whole content of footer.php file, you have created earlier!